# Make a checkbox selection default out of a group

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to make the second checkbox always selected by default even on page reload like the image-

[image]

The user can select other checkboxes later but by default, the second should be selected always.

Here is the checkbox code-

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-wrap">
            <div class="tw-w-full lg:tw-w-1/4">
                <collabmed-loading v-if="!initialised">Loading Patient Info...</collabmed-loading>

                <reception-patient-info
                    class="tw-px-0 tw-pt-0"
                    v-else
                    :patient-id="admissionRequest.patient_id"
                >
                </reception-patient-info>
            </div>

            <div class="tw-w-full lg:tw-w-3/4 lg:tw-pl-5">
                <acemed-card>
                    <acemed-title>
                        Check In Details
                        <template #right>
                            <div v-if="initialised" class="tw-text-lg tw-text-gray-800"><strong>Admission Type:</strong> {{ admissionRequest.admission_type_name }}</div>
                        </template>
                    </acemed-title>

                    <div>
                        <collabmed-loading v-if="!initialised"></collabmed-loading>

                        <div v-else>

                            <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-wrap">
                                <div class="tw-w-full lg:tw-w-1/2">
                                    <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-wrap tw-justify-between">
                                        <div>
                                            <v-tooltip bottom v-if="msetting('inpatient.inpatient_no_prefix')">
                                                <v-btn flat style="min-width: 50px" slot="activator" class="pull-right pt-3">
                                                    {{ msetting('inpatient.inpatient_no_prefix') }}-
                                                </v-btn>
                                                <span>IP Number Prefix</span>
                                            </v-tooltip>
                                        </div>

                                        <div>
                                            <v-text-field
                                                    v-model="obj.admission.inpatient_no"
                                                    class="mr-2"
                                                    label="IP Number"
                                                    hint="Possible Format: #######/YY"
                                            ></v-text-field>
                                        </div>

                                        <div>
                                            <v-tooltip bottom>
                                                <v-btn
                                                        color="primary"
                                                        style="min-width: 50px"
                                                        slot="activator"
                                                        @click="generateIpNumber()"
                                                        :loading="generating"
                                                >
                                                    <v-icon small>mdi-cached</v-icon>
                                                </v-btn>
                                                <span>Generate IP Number</span>
                                            </v-tooltip>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="tw-w-full tw-pt-5 lg:tw-pt-0 lg:tw-w-1/2 lg:tw-pl-5">
                                    <collabmed-date-time-picker
                                        label="Admission Date"
                                        outline
                                        :maxDate="today"
                                        @input="setAdmissionDate"
                                    ></collabmed-date-time-picker>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tw-w-full lg:tw-w-1/2 tw-pt-5">
                                    <div v-if="! obj.admission.external_doctor">
                                        <div v-if="! obj.admission.doctor_id">
                                            <users-search
                                                :roles-like="['doc']"
                                                :label="'Admission Doctor'"
                                                @results="setDoctor"
                                            ></users-search>
                                        </div>
                                        <p v-else class="pt-3 pl-3 border-bottom subheading">Doctor:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <p v-else class="pt-3 pl-3 border-bottom subheading">External Doctor:</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tw-w-full lg:tw-w-1/2 tw-pt-5 lg:tw-pl-5">
                                    <div v-if="obj.admission.doctor_id">
                                        <p class="pt-3 pl-3 border-bottom subheading">
                                            {{ obj.admission.doctor_name }}

                                            <v-btn small color="red" icon dark @click="unsetDoctor()">
                                                <v-icon small>delete</v-icon>
                                            </v-btn>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div v-else>
                                        <v-text-field
                                                v-model="obj.admission.external_doctor"
                                                class="mx-2"
                                                label="External Doctor"
                                                hide-details clearable
                                        ></v-text-field>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tw-w-full lg:tw-w-1/2 tw-pt-5">
                                    <v-autocomplete
                                            v-model="obj.admission.ward_id"
                                            :items="wards"
                                            @change="updateBeds()"
                                            item-text="name"
                                            item-value="id"
                                            label="Select a Ward"
                                            hide-details
                                            outline
                                    ></v-autocomplete>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tw-w-full lg:tw-w-1/2 tw-pt-5 lg:tw-pl-5">
                                    <div v-if="wardCashCharge" class="pl-3">
                                        <p class="font-weight-bold title">Ward Charges</p>
                                        <p>Cash Charge: <strong>{{ wardCashCharge | numberFormat }}</strong></p>
                                        <p>Insurance Charge: <strong>{{ wardInsuranceCharge | numberFormat }}</strong></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tw-w-full lg:tw-w-1/2 tw-pt-5">
                                    <v-autocomplete
                                            v-model="obj.admission.bed_id"
                                            :disabled="! obj.admission.ward_id"
                                            :items="beds"
                                            item-text="name"
                                            item-value="id"
                                            label="Select a Bed"
                                            hide-details
                                            outline
                                    ></v-autocomplete>

                                    <p v-if="overbookingAllowed"><em>Over-booking of beds has been allowed in the system</em></p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tw-w-full lg:tw-w-1/2 tw-pt-5 lg:tw-pl-5">
                                    <v-autocomplete
                                            v-model="obj.admission.charges"
                                            :disabled="! obj.admission.ward_id"
                                            :items="charges"
                                            item-text="name"
                                            item-value="id"
                                            label="Select Other Charge(s)"
                                            class="ml-2"
                                            hide-details multiple
                                            outline chips
                                    ></v-autocomplete>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tw-w-full lg:tw-w-1/2 tw-pt-5">
                                    <v-alert :value="true" v-if="errors.any()" type="error" outline>
                                        <div v-html="errors.display()"></div>
                                    </v-alert>
                                </div>

                                <div class="tw-w-full tw-pt-5">
                                    <v-btn block dark color="primary" class="mt-4" :loading="saveLoader" @click="save()">
                                        Admit Patient
                                        <v-icon class="pl-2">arrow_right_alt</v-icon>
                                    </v-btn>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </acemed-card>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

    export default {
        props: {
            admissionRequestId: {
                required: true,
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                admissionRequestObj: new AdmissionRequest(),
                obj: new Admission(),
                wards: null,
                saveLoader: false,
                beds: [],
                charges: [],
                wardCashCharge: null,
                wardInsuranceCharge: null,
                today: moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss'),
                overbookingAllowed: false,
                generating: false,
            }
        },

        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'getWards',
            ]),

            admissionRequest() {
                return this.admissionRequestObj.selected
            },

            initialised() {
                return this.wards && this.admissionRequest
            },

            saved() {
                return this.obj.saved
            },

            submitted() {
                return this.obj.form.submitted
            },

            contaminated() {
                return this.obj.form.errorDetected;
            },

            errors() {
                return this.obj.form.errors;
            },

            generatedIpNuber() {
                return this.obj.generatedIpNuber
            }
        },

        watch: {
            contaminated(val) {
                if(val) {
                    this.saveLoader = false
                }
            },

            submitted(val) {
                if(val) {
                    this.saveLoader = false
                }
            },

            saved(val) {
                if(val) {
                    this.saveLoader = false
                    this.dialog = false

                    window.location = route('inpatient.admissions.index').relative()
                }
            },

            admissionRequest(val) {
                if(val) {
                    this.obj.admission.admission_request_id = val.id
                    this.obj.admission.visit_id = val.visit_id
                    this.obj.admission.inpatient_no = val.visit.patient.inpatient_no
                    this.obj.admission.patient_id = val.visit.patient.id
                }
            },

            getWards(val) {
                if(val) {
                    this.wards = this.getWards.data
                }
            },

            generatedIpNuber(val) {
                this.generating = false
                if(val)
                    this.obj.admission.inpatient_no = val
            }
        },

        methods: {
            ...mapActions([
                'setWards',
            ]),

            initialise() {
                this.admissionRequestObj.find(this.admissionRequestId)

                this.setWards()

                this.obj.admission.admission_date = this.today

                this.overbookingAllowed = this.$options.methods.msetting('inpatient.allow_overbooking_of_wards') == 1
            },

            updateBeds() {
                let ward = _.find(this.wards, {id: this.obj.admission.ward_id})

                this.wardCashCharge = ward.cash_cost
                this.wardInsuranceCharge = ward.insurance_cost

                this.beds = _.map(ward.beds, item => {
                    let name = "Bed No. " + item.number
                    ! item.is_available ? name += " (Unavailable)" : '';

                    let disabled = ! item.is_available
                    this.overbookingAllowed ? disabled = false : null

                    return {
                        name: name,
                        id: item.id,
                        disabled: disabled
                    }
                })

                let firstAvailableBed = _.find(this.beds, { disabled: false })
                firstAvailableBed ? this.obj.admission.bed_id = firstAvailableBed.id : null

                if(this.charges && this.charges.length && this.charges.length >=2) {
                      // charges[1] = second item
                     this.obj.admission.charges.push(this.charges[1].id)
                  }

                this.charges = _.map(ward.charges, item => {
                    let name = item.name + " - Kshs. " + item.cost;
                    item.type == 'recurring' ? name += " [RECURRING]" : '';

                    return  {
                        id: item.id,
                        name: name
                    }
                })
            },

            setDoctor(doctor) {
                this.obj.admission.doctor_id = doctor.id
                this.obj.admission.doctor_name = doctor.full_name
            },

            unsetDoctor() {
                this.obj.admission.doctor_id = null
                this.obj.admission.doctor_name = null
            },

            generateIpNumber() {
                this.generating = true
                this.obj.generateInpatientNumber()
            },

            setAdmissionDate(datetime) {
                this.obj.admission.admission_date = datetime
            },

            save() {
                this.saveLoader = true
                this.obj.save()
            }

        },

        mounted() {
            this.initialise()
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

The api data looks like-

[image]

When I select `bed`, I call a method to fetch the `charges`. Thats where I have placed the code to select the admission charge where second `charge` item should always be selected.

Comment: Please provide what is the data inside `charges` and `obj`

Comment: done the checkbox are the charges data @NehaSoni

Comment: Please provide the data in text format so we can copy it and reproduce it. In the image its not possible to play with data.

Comment: Also please provide what is the structure of `obj` which you are using for `v-model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to keep the **second item by default selected**, then on the mounted hook, just find the second item's id in your `charges` array, and push this `id` to your `v-model` variable (`obj.admission.charges`) and you should see that the second item is always selected.

Here is the demo-

**NOTE-**
I used your API data inside the data property of Vue as I can't send requests to your server. I also assumed the possible structure of `obj.admission` because you didn't mention it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-container>
          <v-autocomplete
            v-model="obj.admission.charges"
            :disabled="!obj.admission.ward_id"
            :items="charges"
            item-text="name"
            item-value="id"
            label="Select Other Charge(s)"
            class="ml-2"
            hide-details 
            multiple
            outlined
            chips
            >
          </v-autocomplete>
        </v-container>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data() {
         return {
          search: null,
          obj: {
            admission: {
              charges: [],
              ward_id: "something",
            }
          },
          charges: [
           {
            id: 2,
            name: "Nursing Fee",
            cost: "3000.00",
            type: "recurring",
            created_at: "2022-08-23 08:00",
           },
           {
            id: 31,
            name: "Admission Fee",
            cost: "once",
            type: "3000.00",
            created_at: "2022-08-23 08:00",
           },
           {
            id: 32,
            name: "Dr. inpatient visit",
            cost: "3000.00",
            type: "once",
            created_at: "2022-08-23 08:00",
           },
           {
            id: 36,
            name: "Dr. Anne Masicka",
            cost: "3000.00",
            type: "once",
            created_at: "2022-08-23 08:00",
           },
           {
            id: 29,
            name: "Dr. inpatient visit (Dr. Marwa)",
            cost: "3000.00",
            type: "once",
            created_at: "2022-08-23 08:00",
           }
          ]
         }
        },
        mounted() {
         if(this.charges && this.charges.length && this.charges.length >=2) {
         // charges[1] = second item
         this.obj.admission.charges.push(this.charges[1].id)
         }
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has helped but also got another error. I have array of beds. I first choose bed then admissions auto select. incase i change bed it adds another admission and its supposed to add just one

Comment: Do you mean that the Admission item is pushing twice?

Comment: It would be great if you can provide both autocomplete codes in the question, also what do you do when you change the first autocomplete and try to select from the second autocomplete? The question you asked is resolved, this is another error you mentioned depends on your approach to selecting multiple autoselects depend on each other, and to resolve this error, I need more code information.

Comment: added more code @Neha Soni

Comment: solved by first resetting values in charges on each change.

Comment: I was about to type the same comment. Hahaha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250580/discussion-between-ken-mutesh-and-neha-soni).